# ffmpeg video recording gets corrupted

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I run the following command to record video thru ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 10 -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p record.mp4
```

This works fine when I run it thru PowerShell(I stop the recording manually by pressing ctrl + c).

I am trying to do the same thing thru Python and I have created two functions to start and stop the operation.

```
def recThread():
    cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 10 -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p ' + videoFile
    global proc
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.wait()
def stop():
    proc.terminate()
```

However when I run this, the video is corrupted.
I have tried using os.system command instead of subprocess and got the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing the video format to avi and it worked like a charm. After that investigated why the same thing was not working with mp4, and found that if h264 encoder is used, ffmpeg performs an operation at the time of exit to support h264 conversion. `proc.terminate()` does not let ffmpeg exit gracefully.